# Vector layer not displaying in OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector

I have this code from an Udemy course. Everything works except I can not visualize the vector layer. I can see the JSON file - wfs_url correctly but not visualize vectorSource (the data points selected in wfs_url).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Working with Vector Data

```
  var view = new ol.View({
      center: [-9015705,4026797],
      zoom: 11      
      });

   var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: view
  });


var theurl = 'http://localhost:8050/geoserver/richland_postgres/wms';

var bk79 = new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: theurl,
        params: {'LAYERS': 'richland:bk79'},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })    
    });     
 bk79.setOpacity(0.3);



var cqlfilter = 'DWITHIN(geometry,Point(503909 3768402),5000,meters)';

var schoolcql = new ol.layer.Image({
       source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: theurl,
        params: {'LAYERS': 'richland_postgres:schools','CQL_FILTER': cqlfilter},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
    }); 


wfs_url = 'http://localhost:8050/geoserver/richland_postgres/wfs?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.1.0' +
          '&request=GetFeature' +
          '&typename=richland_postgres:schools&' +
          '&CQL_FILTER=' + cqlfilter + '&' +
          'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
          ',EPSG:3857';
prompt('',wfs_url);

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent) {
      return 'http://localhost:8050/geoserver/richland_postgres/wfs?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.1.0' +
          '&request=GetFeature' +
          '&typename=richland_postgres:schools&' +
          '&CQL_FILTER=' + cqlfilter + '&' +
          'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
          ',EPSG:3857';
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
  });

  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
  });


map.addLayer(bk79);
map.addLayer(schoolcql);
map.addLayer(vector);

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you get a JSON output when you enter the url in a browser? Looks like you are missing something here. `srsname=EPSG:3857&'+',EPSG:3857'`

Answer (score 1):

```
wfs_url = 'http://localhost:8050/geoserver/richland_postgres/wfs?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.1.0' +
          '&request=GetFeature' +
          '&typename=richland_postgres:schools&' +
          '&CQL_FILTER=' + cqlfilter + '&' +
          'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
          ',EPSG:3857';
```

You are missing this part `'bbox=' + extent.join(',')` in your code.

This is from [OpenLayers WFS example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html) for reference.

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent) {
      return 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&' +
          'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
          'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});
```

Comment: You don't need a BBOX or srsName for a GetFetaure request ~ the following request works just fine: https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&outputFormat=application/json&

Comment: Yes that should be fine to get the data but I have experienced data not being projected correctly without those. May be I was doing something wrong.